# clickonce versus windows gadget versus silverlight OOB?

Tags: wpf, clickonce, installation, silverlight-oob

We are building for a customer an intranet communication portal (which is based on SharePoint 2010, but I think this is not important).

One of his requirement is to push the latests news in a "widget" (in functional terms), both from the intranet portal and some internet web. All news are available through RSS feeds.

I'm facing a technology choice for this requirement. I see four options, all with pro and cons :

1. Windows gadget :

   - pros :

     - ?
   - cons :

     - coding with js, in 2011 ?
     - deployment and upgrade is probably complex
     - can't embed silverlight in the gadget if the computer is x64
2. WPF rich application, with clickonce deployment

   - pros :

     - easy to style
     - easy to autoupdate
     - can interact with the desktop (tray icon, etc.)
     - virtually no limitation
   - cons :

     - deployment of a clickonce application for all users of the domain ?
3. WPF rich application, with standard setup deployment

   - pros :

     - easy to style
     - can interact with the desktop (tray icon, etc.)
     - virtually no limitation
   - cons :

     - have to deal with an autoupdate feature
4. Silverlight OOB

   - pros :

     - easy to style
     - easy to autoupdate
   - cons :

     - how can I force the application to be installed by all users ?
     - restricted in desktop integration (tray icon, etc.)

I have the feeling the 2nd is best in my case, but I'd appreciate feedbacks.

PS: my customer is running on Win 7 pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think among your options here #2 and #4 are the most viable. 
In silverlight OOB you can have custom mechanism (such as a launch icon) to force user to install the application. Here is an [article](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/12/silverlight-out-of-browser-force-install-pattern.aspx) explaining the same.

Now what I have seen and heard personally so far ClickOnce deployment is very smooth and works just fine. So considering your requirements which requires high desktop interactivity, I would recommend WPF + ClickOnce deployment option. Also since you know your customer's computer environment, you can just have more control over the security and other aspects of your app with WPF app than Silverlight OOB app.

Comment: you confirm what I was feeling. I'm wondering however how to push the app to the end-user. For #2, maybe simply adding in the start menu a shortcut to the .application is enough, for the 4th, it looks like a bit harder. In fact, I'm more confident with the n°2 (if I found a way to autopush the app)

Comment: setup the publish options to deploy using a CD, and an url for the autoupdate looks like what I need. thx :)

Comment: I use ClickOnce for my little applications, and I find it very easy to publish and deploy updates, especially if there's no user data (database, etc) to worry about migrating when you release updates.